# C++ - Deleting a vector element that is referenced by a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, erase

Well, I don't know if it is possible, but the thing would be:

```
struct stPiece
{
  /* some stuff */
  stPiece *mother; // pointer to the piece that created this one
};

vector<stPiece> pieces;
```

Is it possible to erase the piece referenced by 'mother' from pieces, having just that pointer as a reference? How?

Would it mess with the other references? (i.e. if it is not the last element in the vector, by shifting the next elements to other memory positions, while the other '*mothers' remain constant). Of course, I assuming that all the child pieces will be deleted (so I won't need to update any pointer that goes to the same mother).

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing? If you want to remove elements without invalidating other elements, you could try a `list` instead.

Comment: + 1 GMan: Seriously you are complicating your job! Using std::list or creating yourself a custom linked list class would be what you need... not a vector. Why are you trying to do something like this?

Comment: True... I will use list and iterators, then (something which leads me to another question, btw).
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `mother` pointers point directly to elements of the `pieces` vector you will get in all kinds of trouble.

Deleting an element from `pieces` will shift all the positions of the elements at higher indexes. Even inserting elements can make all the pointers invalid, since the vector might need to reallocate it's internal array which might transfer all the elements to new positions in memory.

To answer your main question: You can't delete the element you have the pointer to directly, you would first need search through the vector to find it, or calculate it's index in the vector.

Not storing pointers into `pieces` as `mother` but instead the indexes of the elements would make it a bit more robust, so that at least inserting new elements could not break the existing `mother`s. But deleting from `pieces` would still shift elements to new indexes.

Using a [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) for `pieces` and storing iterators into that as `mother` might be a solution. Iterators of `std::list` are not invalidated if other elements are of that list are removed/added. If different elements can have the same `mother` you still have a problem finding out when to remove the `mother` elements, than maybe using [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) would be simpler.

Comment: Actually, you *can* directly erase the element from the vector with "pieces.erase(the_piece.mother);" because the pointer is the same as the vector iterator to that piece. The main problem (invalidation) still exists, though, as pieces shift position in the vector.

Comment: @Jason: Yeah, that should usually be the case, but it's an implementation detail not really guaranteed by the vector class.

Comment: @sth: You are correct that it is an implementation detail. However, it is most likely that vectors are implemented as arrays and that their iterators are pointers. "Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library" by Scott Meyers discusses how to pass vector data to a legacy (pointer-based) API, and he recommends &v[0] to get the pointer. Therefore, even if the iterator is not a pointer, you could at least use "mother - &pieces[0]" to get the index for erasure. However, both of these are techniques are something I'd avoid anyway ;)

Comment: @Jason, sth: Thank you both for your answers. I was indeed misoriented trying to implement it with vectors.

Comment: @Jason: I had that `mother - &pieces[0]` in mind when I wrote "calculate it's index in the vector" and it would even be guaranteed to work, but since I would strongly recommend to change `mother` to something else than a pointer into the vector I didn't 
elaborate further.

Comment: @Jason: You cannot really use a pointer as an iterator into a vector, while in some implementation of the STL that can be valid, I in others it is not (i.e. VS has checked iterators depending on the compile time options, and those iterators have references back to the container to detect modifications)

Comment: Calculating an iterator as `std::advance( v.begin(), mother-&v[0] )` is a better solution. The pointer arithmetic is sound and will provide the position in the array of the iterator, applying that offset to the begin iterator will provide a valid iterator (that is, ignoring all the iterator/pointer invalidations that can happen when the vector itself is modified --elements added or removed)

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear how the entire data structure is organized and what the consequences are going to be, but it is perfectly possible to erase an element from the vector by having a pointer to that element and the vector itself. You just need to convert the pointer to an iterator first. For example, having a vector

```
vector<stPiece> pieces;
```

and a pointer into that vector

```
stPiece *mother;
```

you can convert the pointer to an index

```
vector<stPiece>::size_type i = mother - &pieces[0];
assert(i < pieces.size());
```

then convert the index to an iterator

```
vector<stPiece>::iterator it = pieces.begin() + i;
```

then erase the element

```
pieces.erase(it);
```

and that's it.

However, it appears that in your data structure you might have multiple long-lived pointers pointing into the same vector. Any attempts to erase elements from such vector will immediately invalidate all these pointers. It theoretically is possible to "restore" their validity, if you do everything carefully, but this is going to a major PITA.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "assuming that all the child pieces will be deleted".

Comment: Thank you. It is nice to see that it could be programmed with vectors; but as many answers have suggested, this might be demanding another data structure.

When I was saying "assuming that all the child pieces will be deleted", I was refering to destroying all the pieces that have that mother when you destroy the mother (and so on, the nieces, et cetera).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can erase the piece referenced by mother.

If you delete the piece referenced by '*mother*', the *mother pointer* in all its children will become dangling, you'll have to take care of this.

About the shifting of elements in the vector, you need not do it, its taken care by the vector class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply...
So... how would you code it?

The shifting can screw the next other references, meaning- the other pointers would be rendered invalid, isn't it?

Comment: @huff: exactly, they will be invalid. How to fix it?depends on who you want to be the mother of a child after the demise of this mother? If none, you can make the mother pointer NULL. If you want the mother's mother to be the new mother, you can change the mother pointer of the children to point to the grandmother, before deleting the mother.

Comment: The problem is more severe than dangling pointers (i.e., other pieces that may have the same mother) that need to be updated. The shifting of the other pieces in the vector when the mother is erased may affect other pieces with different mothers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

The pieces are stored in the vector by value. A vector iterator is therefore a pointer to a piece. This means, then, that a pointer to the mother piece is the same as the vector's iterator at the mother. Vector iterators are invalidated on insertion (all iterators) and erasure (all iterators past the erased iterator), which means memory locations will change and it will be nearly impossible to keep all the pointers updated.

You could store dynamically allocated pieces in the vector, i.e.:

```
vector<stPiece*> pieces
```

The mother pointers won't change as pieces are added/removed to/from the vector. The downsides are:

- you now have to manage memory (new/delete each piece)
- it uses more memory per piece (the pointers in pieces)
- it may be slower because you lose spatial locality (cache efficiency) because it is no longer a contiguous array of stPiece objects

The latter two points may or may not be important in your application.

Comment: storing the pointers in a vector will be detrimental if he already stores them in a non-C++ graph/tree structure.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: With a graph data structure, you often want a master list of nodes (e.g., the pieces vector). This is especially true if you cannot reference the complete graph from a single starting node (e.g., consider a graph consisting of multiple, unconnected subgraphs).

Comment: Huh. You're right; I'm not sure what I was thinking. I recommended a set rather than a vector in my answer…

Answer (score 1):

What you have coded is a singly-linked tree. You probably don't want an object to contain all your `stPiece`s, because that would get in the way of implementing creation and deletion semantics.

I'm guessing that you want to delete `mother` after all the children are gone.

```
set< stPiece * > all_pieces;

struct stPiece {
    boost::shared_ptr< stPiece > const mother;
    stPiece( boost::shared_ptr< stPiece > &in_mother )
     : mother( in_mother ) {
        all_pieces.insert( this );
    }
    ~stPiece() {
        all_pieces.erase( this );
    }
};
```

The key point is that there's a difference between containing some objects and merely being able to iterate over them. If using the most obvious way to create and delete the objects isn't using the container, they probably shouldn't be in it.

Comment: I guess that I'm too used to C and not very good yet at OOP. The thing is that I access the data linearly afterwards, when the tree structure doesn't matter but the elements themselves. But I guess that that's not important, as a function can be written to access it sequentially.

Also, when the mother is erased (and now I'm contradicting myself), I would need to have the option to keep the children alive, orphans of course... so maybe they shouldn't be contained on the mother's structure.

Thank you.